# Is SSH-KEYGEN secure, even when client machine gets hack?

Tags: linux, ssh, ubuntu-14.04, ssh-keygen

1. Suppose there is Client - Server machine.
2. On the Client machine, we have generated an SSH-KEYGEN and stored the same key on Server Machine.
3. Which means, when Client connects Server using SSH, it won't require Password.
4. If Client machine gets hack, then the Server machine is vulnerable to all the attacks?

Comment: This is not a programming question and therefore does not belong on SO; it should have been posted on ServerFault (as I don't think it's deep enough for Security.SE)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: Ok fine. Close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It depends.**

- If the private key is not password-protected on the client, yes, the server is vulnerable and can definitely be accessed. If you want to access the server without password, this is usually the case.
- If it is password-protected, this is not the case. However, you would still have to enter your password upon connecting. Consequently, you don't ease accessing your server (if you don't cache the password), but you still increase the security of your server.

If you absolutely want to access a server without entering your password and without compromising the server if the machine is itself compromised, you want to use a HSM that will hold the private key securely (such as smart cards or YubiKey-like HSMs).

PS: This question would have been better suited for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).